# If a message I starred gets edited, the star state is forgotten

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

### Steps to reproduce

1. Star any recent message
2. Have the OP to edit it
3. Star count remains, but now it appears as though you haven't starred it (star is black)
4. Star it again for it to receive star state again, but the star count goes down (your original star was removed).

Comment: It doesn't remove your star; the AJAX refresh just doesn't include the most current count. Reload the page, don't click the star again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am aware of that, it's a bug nonetheless.

Comment: Bug or no bug it was already reported. (/cc @Martijn) :)